# Acessar dispositivo via CMD

Tags: cmd

Como acessar as pastas internas do android usando o comando do cmd CD.

ex: 
Meu computador\Redmi 4X\Armazenamento interno

Answer (score 3):

Isso não é possível

mas é possível acessar as pastas do android pelo Explorer, iniciando um serviço
FTP no Aparelho com android.

recomendo usar este app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alphainventor.filemanager

ao abrir o app, vá em "Acesso a partir de um PC"
depois clique em Iniciar, vai aparecer um link ftp na tela

depois vá no menu executar do windows e digite "explorer" dê um espaço e cole
o link ftp e dê enter. aí você terá acesso às pastas do seu celular pelo PC

Answer (score 1):

É possível acessar com o ADB.

- Se sua inteção for fazer backup de arquivos (fotos, videos, saves de jogos, etc.), podes usar o **`adb backup -f <file_name> [-[no]apk] <package_name>`**.
- Se quiseres instalar um aplicativo, use: **`adb install [android app].apk`**.
- Para reiniciar o aparelho: **`adb reboot`**.
- Para reiniciar o aparelho em **modo recovery**: **`adb reboot recovery`**.
- Para copiar um arquivo do computador para o aparelho: **`adb push [pasta no computador / nomedoarquivo.extensão] [Pasta no aparelho]`**
- Para copiar um arquivo do aparelho para o computador: **`adb pull [pasta no computador / nomedoarquivo.extensão] [Pasta no computador]`** (Se o diretório não for especificado, o arquivo irá para a pasta do executável ADB ou para a /home.)

Fonte: https://www.androidpit.com.br/adb-drivers-android-windows

Comment: Tendo o ADB e drivers instalados, você executa os comandos pelo cmd.

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Comment: Ok. Vou editar  a resposta. Desculpe o inconveniente.